# Signed integer multiplication with overflow

Tags: c, integer, long-integer, integer-overflow

I want to solve the following problem: assume that we have two `int64_t` numbers `a` and `b`. And we want to find `a * b` if the product fits `int64_t` data type and lowest 64 bits of multiplication result in other way. How can I resolve this ? I know the solution of the similar problem for `uint64_t` data type using long multiplication, can we apply it here ?

Comment: Does your compiler support 128 bit integers as an extension?

Comment: it does, but i shouldn’t use it

Comment: It goes along the lines of `if(INT64_MAX / a > b) overflow = true;`. You also have to consider negative numbers and `INT64_MIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a sheer act of computational devilry, `int64_t` and `uint64_t` multiplication have the same bit pattern.

Therefore you can compute `1ULL * a * b` and assign that to a `uint64_t`: the coefficient is there to force type conversion of `a` and `b`. Note that if a compiler supports `int64_t` then it is required to support `uint64_t` as well.

Then it's a matter of comparing the size of this product cf. `a` and `b` to see if it will fit into an `int64_t`. Wrap-around will have taken place if the product is smaller (in the unsigned sense) than either `a` and `b`.

Comment: but i also want to find the lowest bits of correct product

Comment: @envygrunt: The least significant bits will be correctly reported.

Comment: oh, okay so. ill try to implement this

Comment: In theory `ULL` doesn't have to correspond to 64 bits. It would be more correct to use `UINT64_C(1)`, but that gives `uint_least64_t` so it's not entirely correct either. The best solution is therefore to simply cast to `uint64_t`.

Comment: @Lundin: The devil in me shied away from that; so long as it's *at least* 64 bits (which 1ULL is) you'll get away with it, although the answer needs one more edit, which I'll do now.

Comment: Just a pedantic remark - it seems insane not to have `unsigned long long` as 64 bits.

Comment: @Lundin: You know where I sit with pedantry;-) My submission is that this answer works even if, for example `unsigned long long` was 65 bits, let alone a perhaps more realistic 128 bits.

Comment: @Bathsheba your overflow test is only half true, because when the product is greater than both operands, it does not mean there was *no* overflow. For example in the simpler 8-bit case `73 * 4F = 237D` is an overflow but `7D` is greater than either operand.